# how can I control undewater sunbeams in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics, effects

I'm trying to make an underwater render in Cycles and I was wondering if there's a way to control the sun rays, like the position, direction and quantity without affecting the overall lighting too much (the underwater objects need to be clear and not in dark spots).
I'm using a volumetric cube and a plane with the ocean modifier for the surface.
For lighting I want to use an hdri, and a light if it's necessary for the sun rays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry I forgot you used Cycles.
If you used Eevee, would this be of any help?

In my opinion, rendering Cycles volumetrics can be very time consuming. In some situations, it might make sense to composite Eevee volumetrics on top of Cycles renders.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Upload your blend file here, it's better: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I tried but it hangs.... and can't upload. I waited like 10 minutes :(
Ok I try again, but hopes are not up

Comment: Ah, now I get how it works :P It wasn't like Imgur-upload